# What's the criteria for the Electorate badge?

Tags: support, badges

The description says "Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions." So, to recap: Voted on questions, and 25% were... *questions?* (As opposed to the questions that aren't questions?)

Does that mean you voted 600 times (questions and answers), and 25% were on questions only? If so, I should have gotten this badge 200 votes ago. And I assume this applies to only the vote count that shows up on my profile (i.e. it doesn't include voting-up comments)?

So, one of three things is wrong: (1) the description of the Electorate badge (it's at least confusing); (2) the computation to award the Electorate badge; or (3) my count of my question votes. Given that so few seem to have it, I'm thinking it might be #2, and at least #1 should be clarified.

Is there a way to tell what my real percentage is? Lately I've been going through the top votes, the bottom votes, and everything in between to try to help those really interesting questions get closer to the top. Perhaps I was voting on questions too frequently, so the votes got discounted?

---

As an aside, the badge is a strange incentive: because I was close, I wouldn't vote up answers as often as I should. Perhaps the Electorate badge limit should be absolute (150 questions) and not a percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you must have voted on 600 questions and 25% of your total votes must be on questions.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/6329

Right now you've cast 801 votes, so unless at *least* 600 of those votes were on questions, you won't get the badge.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I parsed the statement wrong. So with my estimate of 300 votes on questions, I would still need to vote for 300 more. [Last part about statement parsing made up to reach character limit.]

Comment: BTW, for the record, the last part about making up the mistaken parsing was just a joke in reference to your recent Tweet. I did find the question hard to parse right, but now that I see the correct interpretation, it's hard to revert out of it.

Comment: Wouldn't 25% of 800 be 200?  and not 300?

Comment: @walter nope 600 is the *minimum* in this case.